# ionic: not able to do prod build appRate ionic4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, ionic-native, capacitor

I am getting below error, why and how to fix this? :
`ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(27,15): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'`
[image]

in Vscode its shows like [image]

Basically, I am trying to add a rating feature in my ionic app. First, I followed this ionic [AppRate tutorial](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate/)

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apprate
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/app-rate@beta
```

and in app.modules.ts file i added below code:

```
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate';
...
...
providers: [  ...
   AppRate, ...  //i added this in this file 
  ],
    ...
    ...
```

**Ionic info**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `@ionic-native/whatever@beta` you have to import the `ngx` folder instead of the base folder. So for `AppRate` it should be:

`import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate/ngx';`

See that you already did that on the `NativeStorage` and the commented `Network` plugin imports.